# Is there any way to use itertools groupby to remove adjacent duplicating items in a list, but keep the original index?

Tags: python, list, indexing, python-itertools

For example, if I have a list `[1,2,2,3,2,2,1]`, I would like to return `[1,2,3,2,1]`with index (0,1,3,4,6).

I'm not familiar with groupby, I learned how to eliminate adjacent duplicate items, but it is possible to somehow also extract index with groupby()? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you can combine `itertools.groupby`, with `enumerate()` and the right `key=`

For example:

```
lst = [1,2,2,3,2,2,1]

from itertools import groupby

rv, index = [], []
for v, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda k: k[1]):
    rv.append(v)
    index.append(next(g)[0])

print(rv)
print(index)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the last part index.append(next(g)[0]). 
I also tried to get index of the last duplicates instead of first duplicates such as [0,2,3,5,6], I did figure it out but didn't understand it. 
`for x in g: 
        continue 
#outside for loop 
rv.append(v)
index.append(x[0])`
Thank you.

Comment: @kuku `index.append(next(g)[0])` gets first value from iterator `g` (the `next(g)` part) and then gets first element from this value (the `[0]` part) and appends it to list `index`. Iterator `g` contains the groups from `enumerate(lst)` iterator. First group in this example is `(0, 1)`, second group `(1, 2), (2, 2)`, third group `(3, 3)` and so on...  With `for x in g: continue` you simply iterate over whole group and `x` will be then last element of the group.

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense now, I finally got what the groups are, I was totally misunderstanding it. Very much appreciated.